# LFTP adds ";type=i" to remote file name

Tags: cygwin, lftp

I'm using LFTP version 4.7.8 under cygwin.
It automatically adds `";type=i"` (or `";type=a"` if I do `put -a`) to remote file name. What's more, `mv` command does not work : `mv: Operation not supported: 501 Not Implemented (MOVE)`

No issues at all using FileZilla on the same FTP server.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: the `mv`message seems coming from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you have decided to access your FTP server via an HTTP proxy, a protocol that the LFTP doco calls *HFTP*.  You've encoded this decision either in the LFTP configuration file or in an `ftp_proxy` environment variable.

Your proxy is supposed to be decoding the `;type=i` and `;type=a` parts of the URLs that LFTP is sending to it, per RFC 1738 § 3.2.2.  It isn't doing that, and is incorrectly passing them along to the target FTP server.  There's a configuration file switch, documented in the LFTP user manual, to work around that, by omitting the FTP type suffix from the URLs sent to the proxy.

In HFTP mode, the `mv` command in the LFTP client becomes a `MOVE` command with a `Destination:` header to the HTTP proxy (which it in turn is expected to translate into FTP `RNFR` and `RNTO` verbs sent on to the target FTP server appropriately).  Your HTTP proxy does not implement a `MOVE` HTTP verb at all.

It seems that your HTTP proxy is quite bad at FTP over HTTP.

Your choices are:

- Get a better HTTP proxy that can handle HFTP.
- Don't use an HTTP proxy for FTP in the first place.
- Stop trying to rename files.  ☺

## Further reading

- Christoph Lameter et al. (2017-08-10).  [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html). *General Commands Manual*.  lftp.yar.ru.
- T. Berners-Lee, L. Masinter, and M. McCahill (1994-12).  "[FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2)". *Uniform Resource Locators*  RFC 1738.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer. The HTTP proxy is quiet old, and not great indeed. It is not under my control. The option `set ftp:use-type no` fixed the issue indeed (and, thus, no need for a `mv` anymore :).